# Shell Script not working correctly. What wrong am I doing here?

Tags: bash, shell, syntax

[image: Screenshot depicting the issue]

Please let me know what is error am I doing here. I am getting this output irrespective of the values of a and b variables.

Comment: `if [ $a = $b ]` note the space before `]`. And PLEASE DON'T post photos of text. Copy & paste text.

Comment: When you're asking for help, you’ll get more/better answers if you don’t post screenshots or photos. Cut & paste the text directly into the message.

Why?
1. It's easier for people to read it.
2. It allows those reading it to cut & paste the text, making it easier to work on solving your problem.
3. It makes it searchable, so that someone can find this thread when Googling for information in the future.
4. A screen reader can't read a picture which limits access to some in our community.

Comment: Please replace image with its text. Please take a look at [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net) is good at spotting common mistakes like this (and will also point out some other problems with your script).

Answer (score 1):

You have to rewrite `[ $a == $b]` to `[ $a == $b ]`.

Comment: What if `a="Something with spaces"`. Try `a="== =="; b=""; if [ $a == $b ]; then echo equal; fi`. Conclusion: Use quotes `[ "$a" == "$b" ]`

Answer (score 0):

Strictly speaking, **==** is used to compare strings. You'd like to use **-eq** to compare integer values.
In the following example string comparison will fail even if integer value is the same:

```
    a=010
    b=10
    if [ $a == $b ] ; then
            echo "A == B"
    else
            echo "A <> B"
    fi
```

But if we change test operate to **-eq**

```
    a=010
    b=10
    if [ $a -eq $b ] ; then
            echo "A == B"
    else
            echo "A &lt;&gt; B"
    fi
```

Result will be A == B

Comment: Interestingly `[[ $a -eq $b ]]` and `(( a == b ))` will give different results: "010" will be treated as an octal number, and 8 != 10